# selenium webdriver can't get pass loading of javascript table

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm building a web-scrapper to extract public data from a website's table

This is my code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)

# find enter button and click on it
agree_enter_button = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'AGREE')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", agree_enter_button)

# find search fields
from_date_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="criteria_file_date_start"]')
to_date_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="criteria_file_date_end"]')
full_name_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="criteria_full_name"]')

# fill the fields with inputs
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", full_name_input, first_name + ' ' + last_name)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", from_date_input, from_date)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", to_date_input, thru_date)

# find search button and click on it
search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="btn btn-success w-40"]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search_button)
```

It seems to be working OK until I click the search button.

When I click the button manually, it takes about 5 seconds for the table to load with all the records via JavaScript.

But when I try to load it within the code it stays stuck on loading: (I'm disabling the headless mode and see it stuck on loading)

[image]

If I try to wait for the loading screen to pass, it doesn't.

When I try to not wait and get the table like this:

```
html = driver.page_source
df = pd.read_html(html)
```

I get an empty table with the wrong shape.

When I try to not wait and get the tbody of the table like this:

```
results_set = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'panel_resultset')
content = results_set.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'collapse-content')
grid = content.find_element(By.ID, 'grid_container')
scroll = grid.find_element(By.ID, 'grid_scroll')
table = scroll.find_element(By.ID, 'grid')
tbody = grid.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'tbody')
trs = tbody.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
```

I get 0 rows in trs (probably because the table isn't loaded, but its code exists?)

When I try to use WebDriverWait:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
     EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'loading_panel'))
# OR
tbody = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-widget-content ui-iggrid-tablebody ui-ig-record ui-iggrid-record")))
```

It gets stuck waiting forever either on the loading panel or the tbody.

Seems to me the problem is with the loading screen which seems to load quickly when visiting the site manually but gets stuck on loading when using selenium web-driver.

Any help with solving this will be much appreciated!!

Comment: Are you using same Chrome version? (on python code and manually test or main chrome). Try to remove headless mode, stop/wait code after .get(url) and click element, still get infinite loading?

Comment: @Wonka I'm not sure how to compare versions, but the screenshot provided in the post is taken when I disable headless mode and wait after .get(url) and clicking the search button. I added a time.sleep(100) right after and yes, still infinite loading.

Comment: try to run "chromedriver --version" on terminal and go main chrome you use where you said you click manually > Help> About Google Chrome

Comment: @Wonka the chromedriver version is 121.0.6167.85, my chrome version is 121.0.6167.140. I'm trying to figure out what to do with this

Comment: There are almost same version, can you share url? i will try on my version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256754/discussion-between-wonka-and-havingnohead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we talked in discussion in chat, and you are stuck loading, this is other option to get data but I was not able to send on chat cause is too long

This is curl example, you can use Request library or any library or just execute curl command from python

Check there is your input data shared to Search

response is on JSON format

```
curl 'https://recording.seminoleclerk.org/DuProcessWebInquiry/Home/CriteriaSearch?criteria_array=[{"name_direction":true,"full_name":"jim","file_date_start":"12/10/2023","file_date_end":"02/01/2024","greater_than_page":false,"q_NWNW":false,"q_NWNE":false,"q_NWSE":false,"q_NWSW":false,"q_NENW":false,"q_NENE":false,"q_NESW":false,"q_NESE":false,"q_SWNW":false,"q_SWNE":false,"q_SWSW":false,"q_SWSE":false,"q_SENW":false,"q_SENE":false,"q_SESW":false,"q_SESE":false,"q_q_search_type":false}]' --globoff
```

Comment: thanks a lot, although its a different method, it works perfectly.